# Android MapBox inflating error

Tags: android, android-layout, mapbox

Hello I try to use MapBox Android SDK, but I have problem.

When APK is launched error shows like :      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView

I use Android studio.

My XML Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapid="map ID "/>


     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/llCardInfo"         
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background="#CCffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">        
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.99">
       <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="70dp"
             android:text="Hello" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
       <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/ivCloseCard"
           android:visibility="invisible"
           android:src="@drawable/close_card_anim"
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And This is Fragment.

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':lib:SlidingMenu')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-17.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.2.jar')
    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:0.3.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar')

}
```

Comment: Show your gradle file

Comment: I have added Gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being caused by overlapping versions of OkHttp.  Mapbox Android 0.3.0 uses OkHttp 1.x and the provided Gradle dependency lists also contains OkHttp 2.0.  This causes confusion at runtime with this error message being the result.

Mapbox Android 0.5.0 has addresses this issue and will allow parallel use of OkHttp 2.0.

Comment: @Bradleege Does this issue resolved into new version of android sdk? I am faicng same issue while using 0.7.0

Comment: @PankajKumar Should be still fine in 0.7.0.  OkHttp 2.2.0 is the current version in the SDK.  Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @BradLeege I am tring with eclipse not on studio. Is it the reason? Can you please confirm me that I will not get this error while using into Studio?

Comment: @PankajKumar The IDE shouldn't matter in terms of it working.  Eclipse can use Maven to include the SDK or it can also hardwire it in via .apklib.  The biggest issue is making sure that all the library dependencies are added to the implementing project's class path.  Please see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk#eclipse-hardcoding---not-recommended for more information.

Comment: @BradLeege  can u pls tell me how to resolve i m using eclipse

Comment: @erum If you're seeing this and are hardcoding the Mapbox Android SDK into Eclipse the likely issue is that there are multiple versions of OkHttp on the classpath.  Please see the GitHub repo for detailed instructions on how to install on Eclipse.

Comment: @BradLeege  can u pls help me i m still unable to run the prj in eclipse after adding all libraries